# What is a good size for profile pictures?

Tags: profile

I'm trying to implement profile pictures on a site that I'm working on, and I'm wondering what is a good size for the pictures (what users should upload and what the picture will be ultimately resized down to). I would think that the image should be small enough that it would load fast on mobile devices, but be big enough so that it wouldn't look terrible, but I don't know what the exact size should be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it also depends on the nature of the websites. Many sites require users to upload actual photos rather than avatars that may not represent their real features. Also, if it is just an image for the purpose of a thumbnail and that users can click on to enlarge then the size is not as important. My suggestion is to do some performance testing to benchmark the optimal size of the image.

You can see some suggestions for [avatar](https://developer.atlassian.com/design/1.5/foundations/avatars/) design on the Atlassian Development Guidelines for some ideas.